# Do we have any ways to use chrome driver along with karate for UI test

Tags: karate

Is it possible to achieve using both the Chrome WebDriver and Karate Driver simultaneously? I am attempting to leverage functionalities from the chromedriver that are not functioning in Karate, such as drag and drop. Below is my code for reference

````
    Scenario: Sceanrio to test chrome driver and karate 
    * def ChromeDriver = Java.type('org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver')

    # Set the path to the ChromeDriver executable
    * def chromedriverPath = 'driver_executable_path'

    # Set system property to use the ChromeDriver executable
    * java.lang.System.setProperty('webdriver.chrome.driver', chromedriverPath)

    * def chromeOptions = Java.type('org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions')
    * def options = new chromeOptions()
    * options.addArguments('--remote-debugging-port=9222')
    # Launch Chrome browser
    * def driver = new ChromeDriver(options)

    # Perform actions using Selenium
    * driver.get('https://demo.automationtesting.in/Index.html')
    # some action via selenium - e.g. -> drag and drop as I could see its a bigger pain.

    # Attach the browser session with Karate
    * configure driver = { type: 'chrome', start: false, attach: 'https://demo.automationtesting.in/Index.html'}

    # all other actions via karate ?
    * delay(3000)
    * input('input#email', 'karate')
    * screenshot()```
````

Comment: maybe, but why don't you contribute code to karate to improve drag and drop ? at the very least provide a sample app and flow, that you can submit as a feature request. you are on your own otherwise

Comment: Drag and drop is just a example which doesn't work.. there are some more e.g. beautiful mui components..I don't mind using the best of both tools, but my main question is: What's wrong with the code above?